# iOS Firebase reset password locally within app, not on redirect url page

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, redirect, firebase-authentication

I am writing code to allow a user to reset their password using Firebase. Currently, if the ask to reset their password, I use the sendPassword Reset button as follows:

```
    @IBAction func sendConfirmationEmail(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = email {
            auth.sendPasswordReset(withEmail: email, completion: { error in
                if let error = error {
                    // Handle errors
                }
            })
        }

    }
```

This successfully sends the verification email. I then click the link in the email, which takes me to a webpage where I can enter a new password and click submit. The page then tells me I can sign in using my new password. However, I would like to have the user enter their new password in my app. Ideally, when the user clicks the link, they will be redirected to my app and I can segue to the correct screen, where they can then enter a new password and then I can call the updatePassword firebase function.

If this is not possible, I would at least like to have the user automatically redirected to the app upon submitting their new password. I have explored doing this with actionCodeSettings, but I do not want to write my own webpage for entering a new password.

Comment: Opening your App using a URL is not difficult, it's called "URL Schemes". Look here for a simple tutorial.
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-make-your-app-open-with-a-custom-url-scheme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way within the existing API to change the behavior you're describing.

If you want to have a different flow for the password reset of Firebase, you will have to implement that yourself. In that case you'll typically end up using the Admin SDK (in a trusted environment) to perform the sensitive operations, such as [changing the actual password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ActionCodeSettings` to redirect the user to your app to complete the password reset. You have to set `handleCodeInApp` to true and you have to configure FDL and intercept the redirect to the app. Once you do so, you can get the code from the deep link and ask the user to `confirmPasswordReset` using the new password and the code from the deep link.

[Learn more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/passing-state-in-email-actions) on how to handle the link from your app.

However, you still need to write a web fallback in case the user opens the link on a different device where the app is not installed. You could display an error message asking the user to open the link on the same device. It should be minimal code.